# Diferenciar valores obtenidos desde un mismo Widget usado varias veces en Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Tengo una clase padre donde uso múltiples veces un Widget que tengo creado en una clase hijo, y retorno el valor seleccionado del Widget con un callback(), de esta manera:

```
  void callback(String value) {
    setState(() {
      //print('callback: $value');
    });
  }
```

El problema es que uso varias veces el mismo Widget y todos los valores se retornan de la misma manera, a través de este callback(), entonces no sé cómo diferenciar los valores dependiendo de cuál Widget usado es el valor retornado, esto con el objetivo de poder almacenar los valores en variables distintas.

De esta manera le paso el callback() al Widget que tengo en otra clase, el cual es un DropDownMenu:

```
DropDownMenu(
                        itemsList: list2,
                        dropdownVal: 'Día 1',
                        callback: callback),
                  ),
```

Y esta es la clase del Widget DropDownMenu:

```
class DropDownMenu extends StatefulWidget {

  final String dropdownVal;
  final List<String> itemsList;
  Function callback;

  DropDownMenu({
    Key key,
    @required this.itemsList,
    @required this.dropdownVal,
    @required this.callback,
  });

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => new _DropDownMenuState();
}

class _DropDownMenuState extends State<DropDownMenu> {

  String dropdownValue;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    if(dropdownValue == null){
      dropdownValue = widget.itemsList.first;
    }

    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      height: 60,
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          horizontal: 10, vertical: 5),
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
      child: DropdownButton<String>(
        value: dropdownValue,
        isExpanded: true,
        icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
        iconSize: 42,
        underline: SizedBox(),
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Color(0xFFff4c4c),
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          fontFamily: 'Lato',
        ),
        onChanged: (String newValue) {
          setState(() {
            dropdownValue = newValue;
            widget.callback(newValue);
          });
        },
        items: widget.itemsList.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
          //print(value);
          return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
            value: value,
            child: AutoSizeText(
              value,
              textAlign: TextAlign.left,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontFamily: 'Lato',
                color: Color(0xFFff0000),
              ),
              maxLines: 3,
              maxFontSize: 15.0,
              overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
              minFontSize: 2.0,
            ),
          );
        }).toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
```

¿Hay alguna manera de diferenciar los valores retornados de un mismo Widget usado varias veces?

Espero puedan ayudarme,
desde ya,
muchas gracias.

Comment: Y si al constructor del hijo le pasas un int o string para identificarlos y haces que el callback lo use para guardarlo en la variable que quieres?.

Comment: @loki Es buena idea, eso podría funcionar... Pero si genero los objetos dentro de una lista automáticamente, es posible generar variables para enviarlas por el constructor al hijo, es decir, ir enviando var1, var2, var3, etc. automáticamente?

Comment: @loki Creo que eso no es posible en Dart :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una forma de solucionarlo es crear un callback así dentro del widget: `Function(String, int) callback;` el int puede ser un identificador para el widget.

Respecto a lo que entiendo de esta parte de tu pregunta, de enviar variables generadas automaticamente revisa STREAM, o algún manejador de estados.